# Page break with a longtable in multicolumn

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, multicol

I am trying to reproduce a book which contains many tables printed on two columns to save some vertical space. The text before & after the tables is not concerned by this multi-column style.

I could typeset the tables in a “two small tables side to side in a bigger one” way, but that would not really separate content and design.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex) solves the first part of the problem, displaying the (long) table on two columns.

The tables are not meant to float [like in this case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161827/balanced-longtables-multicol-and-page-breaks) and that seems to bring the same problem of page breaking back: the text after the table does not break, nor the table if it is too long.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{multicols}{2}

\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
\makeatletter\col@number\@ne\makeatother
\begin{longtable}{lll}
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3
\end{longtable}
\unskip
\unpenalty
\unpenalty}
\unvbox\ltmcbox

\end{multicols}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work better if one set the longtable outside the multicols environment

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{\hsize=\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep
\makeatletter\col@number\@ne\makeatother
\begin{longtable}{lll}
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
col 1 & col 2 & col 3
\end{longtable}
\unskip
\unpenalty
\unpenalty}

\begin{multicols}{2}


\unvbox\ltmcbox

\end{multicols}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(David's answer in [Balancing long table inside multicol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex) has the same problem if one add enough text before the multicols.)

Comment: The manual says that longtable will not work in twocolumn or multicolumn mode.  No clue as to why that should be.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Sure and I would avoid it. But it is David who suggested the code to make it working nevertheless in some cases.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: thank you for your answer. Extracting the box from the `multicols` environment solves the text page breaking.
It does not seem to solve the problem if the table needs to break though.
I think I’ll consider using the `paste` program to build my tables before typesetting them, as suggested David Carlisle there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193390/longtable-next-to-longtable-no-multicolumn#comment472789_193390